# Directional Sending and Omnidirectional recieving

Tags: wireless

I am currently working in networking research. I want to establish an environment with a wireless sensor network, where the sensor nodes have the following properties:

1. Sensor nodes must be directional and have sectors
2. Receiving nodes will be omni-directional
3. Receiving or transmitting will be directional

My question is primarily about properties 2 & 3.

Is it possible to establish environment of the sensor nodes with both omni-directional receiving and directional transmitting?

Some links,examples or any solution will help me a lot.

Comment: This seems to be more of an RF engineering question, but I see no radio site on StackExchange. Maybe the Physics or EE people know more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think building this network has two separate problems: Building the desired directional properties from available antennas, and splitting the transmit and receive functionalities.

Directional antennas should be straightforward (but not necessarily easy.) Select one (or more) standard antenna designs which fit the "sector" properties you want. Cisco has some [great information](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/wireless/ps7183/ps469/prod_white_paper0900aecd806a1a3e.html), and there is some directional antenna [discussion here on NE.](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/327/omnidirectional-antennas-and-the-dipole-antenna/339#339) Since you are in a research environment, you could further tune your antenna properties with specially crafted and positioned grounded metal plates (etc) to tune your antennas. I would expect you'll need an accurate way to measure the signal strengths from your antennas.

There is also information on [beam forming solutions from Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/wireless/ps5678/ps11983/white_paper_c11-722622.html).

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge (which is not advanced) directionality is generally a function of the antenna so I suppose that you could use separate transmit and receive antennas such that one could be directional and the other omnidirectional.

Another alternative would be [beamforming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamforming), which is a signal-processing technique that seems to be simulating directionality in software.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into a technology similar to either Xirrus (access point arrays) or Ruckus (antenna arrays).

Both provide a means to listen in a "omnidirectional" sense, but transmit in a more directional means.